# After the Covid pandemic, will there be an aircraft manufacturer which produced a combi aircraft anymore?

Tags: airliner, aircraft-production

On this covid pandemic, there will be many changes in all of air travel, one of them is Combi aircraft to be rebuilt again.

Comment: Welcome to the stack! We’re glad to have you, and look forward to hearing more from you in the future. Please keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum, and opinion-based questions should be avoided. Questions like this can’t have a satisfactory, objective answer, since no one can predict the future or how the covid-19 outbreak will progress. I hope this doesn’t discourage you from posting again. Have a nice week.

Answer (score 1):

The business case for combi's has little to do with air travel in that regard.  The only significant change you will see industry wide, as air travel recovers over the next several years, is every airliner adding HEPA filtration to its cabin air recirculation system.  It's a good time to be a manufacturer of HEPA retrofit filtration kits.

Comment: So actually, Combi is unrelevant now? Why?